# Creating a new array based on values in existing subarrays, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array containing subarrays, similar to this:

```
someArray = [[Bill, 1], [Ted, 2], [Steve, 2], [Alex, 3]]
```

I am trying to push the first value in each subarray into a new array the same amount of times as the second value. So for the example above I'd like it to look like this:

```
newArray = [Bill, Ted, Ted, Steve, Steve, Alex, Alex, Alex]
```

I'm able to access the values in the subarrays using these nested `for` loops, but this is as far as I can get with it:

```
for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) {
// inner loop applies to sub-arrays
for (var j=0, len2=data[i].length; j<len2; j++) {
    // accesses each element of each sub-array in turn
    names.push(data[i][j]);
        //adds each element to a new array
```

Comment: If `Bill` etc are meant to be *strings*, they need to be enclosed in quotes. Are they meant to be strings?

Comment: Your `data[i]` is a pair whose `[0]` is the element to repeat, and whose `[1]` is the number to repeat; so, not `len2=data[i].length`, but `len2=data[i][1]`; not `names.push(data[i][j])`, but `names.push(data[i][0])`

Comment: Thank you @Amadan, this is exactly where I was going wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this concisely with `reduce`, pushing the required number of items to the accumulator on each iteration:

```js
const someArray = [['Bill', 1], ['Ted', 2], ['Steve', 2], ['Alex', 3]];
const output = someArray.reduce((a, [repeatItem, repeatCount]) => {
  a.push(...Array.from({ length: repeatCount }, () => repeatItem));
  return a;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```

This will work no matter the data type of the first item in the sub-arrays, but note that if the `repeatItem`s are *objects* (or arrays or functions), you'll have multiple *references* to the same object, rather than deep clones of the objects. (a mutation to one of the objects will be seen from every reference to that object)

Answer (score 1):

If you like to use your solution itself that is corrected and will work fine, you can look at code below and its differences with your own code:

```
var data = [["Bill", 1], ["Ted", 2], ["Steve", 2], ["Alex", 3]];
var names=[];
for (var i=0, len=data.length; i<len; i++) 
   for (var j=0; j<data[i][1]; j++) 
       names.push(data[i][0]);
console.log(names);
```

But using `reduce` or `map` function is more stylish:

```
var someArray = [["Bill", 1], ["Ted", 2], ["Steve", 2], ["Alex", 3]];
var names=
    Array.prototype.concat.apply(
        [],
        someArray.map(function(d){
            var r=[], i=0;
            for(;i<d[1];i++) r.push(d[0]);
            return r;
        })
     );
 console.log(names);
```

And `reduce` version:

```
var names=
 someArray.reduce(function(a, d){
        var i=0;
        for(;i<d[1];i++) a.push(d[0]);
        return a;
}, [])
console.log(names);
```

Answer (score 0):

@tdehnel, the idea you have used is right, just that it isn't executed right. Just minor changes buddy.

1. `len2` shouldn't be length of `data[i]`, because `data[i].length` is
   always 2, because each subarray has length 2. Instead you want it to
   loop the number of times represented by the second element of each
   subarray I suppose, which is `data[i][1]`.Hence, `len2 =
   data[i][1]`.
2. As @Amadan mentioned, you're supposed to be pushing `data[i][0]` instead of `data[i][j]`.

The code is as follows:

```
for (var i = 0, len = data.length; i < len; i++) {
    // inner loop applies to sub-arrays
    for (var j = 0, len2 = data[i][1]; j < len2; j++) {
       // accesses each element of each sub-array in turn
       names.push(data[i][0]);
       //adds each element to a new array
```

Else, you could do as @CertainPerformance has suggested which is a simple way too.